# How to copy found text (highlighted) in TextEdit

Tags: copy-paste, textedit

I'm looking for copying the patterns that I find. For example for this, I would like to copy all the "bcbc":

[image]

and being able to paste it somewhere like "bcbcbcbcbcbcbcbcbcbc" (bcbc x5).

Do you know any way to do it?

Thanks in advance.
Regards.
Rafael.

---

This is the pattern exactly:

[image]

Comment: What is it you need this for, where does it need to be pasted?

Comment: I need to extract some patterns from html, but the patterns should change and I can find them very quick with TextEdit

Comment: Can you give a sample pattern? I don't believe text edit has support for this, but I'm sure there is another application that can do this. (I just don't know of it)

Comment: @zggz12 I updated the question ;)

Comment: Have you tried `regex`?